# java.io.FileNotFoundException config\security.properties when running from IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

When I run my application from IDEA I'm getting the following warning (see below). When running the same code from outside IDEA, this warning does not appear (even though the file isn't really there as well.
Seems like everything is working OK, but still, it's kind of annoying... how can I get rid of it?
(BTW I'm using Tomcat embedded).

```
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\config\security.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.Utility.getPropertiesFromFile(Utility.java:56)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.POAEJBORB.<clinit>(POAEJBORB.java:83)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:340)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:308)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:351)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.createORB(ORBManager.java:140)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.init(ORBManager.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory.<init>(SerialInitContextFactory.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.InitialContextHelper.getInitialContext(InitialContextHelper.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configureJndiResources(WebComponent.java:805)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:530)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:314)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet(Tomcat.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\...\config\ejb.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.Utility.getPropertiesFromFile(Utility.java:56)
    at com.sun.enterprise.iiop.J2EEInitializer.<init>(J2EEInitializer.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.internal.Interceptors.PIORB.registerORBInitializers(PIORB.java:373)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.internal.Interceptors.PIORB.parseProperties(PIORB.java:343)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.internal.TxPOA.TxPIORB.parseProperties(TxPIORB.java:116)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.internal.corba.ORB.set_parameters(ORB.java:449)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.internal.POA.POAORB.set_parameters(POAORB.java:152)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.internal.Interceptors.PIORB.set_parameters(PIORB.java:332)
    at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:353)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.createORB(ORBManager.java:140)
    at com.sun.enterprise.util.ORBManager.init(ORBManager.java:69)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory.<init>(SerialInitContextFactory.java:35)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:408)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:433)
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:672)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:313)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:244)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.InitialContextHelper.getInitialContext(InitialContextHelper.java:56)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configureJndiResources(WebComponent.java:805)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.configure(WebComponent.java:530)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.configure(ServletContainer.java:314)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:604)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:207)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:376)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:559)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat$ExistingStandardWrapper.loadServlet(Tomcat.java:855)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5123)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5407)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: I'd probably rather worry why the code is working outside IDEA when the file is still missing. That a missing file/bad file path produces a FileNotFoundException looks rather normal to me.

Comment: I don't worry it's just really annoying

Comment: Doesn't tomcat use a different security model for accessing files directly? Could it cause the variation in behaviour? Is it feasible to instead build the file you need into a war and access it via the classloarder, rather than from the file system?

Comment: I don't have any war file. My Tomcat is embedded.

Answer (score 0):

From your question it isn't clear which logger is logging this warning (looks like one of the Tomcat's) and neither which version of Tomcat you are using, but you can generally fine tune the log levels in Tomcat. More information here:
http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/logging.html

I wouldn't really advise you to disable warnings however.